# Python tests in more than one file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automated-tests, test-explorer

I'm using `unittest` library to run some tests for a Python/Django application, using Visual Studio Code. They work just fine. The only issue is that I have the tests located in more than one file, and I can't get VS Code to run them all at one single click, I have to run each file separately. My structure goes something like this:

```
/applications (folder)
   /folder1
      python_file_1.py
      python_file_2.py
      ...
      test_first.py
   /folder2
      python_file_3.py
      python_file_4.py
      ...
      test_second.py
      test_third.py
```

This produces this tree in the test explorer:

[image]

The files `test_*.py` contain my three sets of tests but, like I said, I can only run them one at a time. If I click on the `play` button at `/applications` level, VS Code only runs the tests in `test_integration_comun.py` file. Is there a way to run all 3 with just one click?

This is the `settings.json` file that VS Code added when I configured `unittest`:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./applications",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

To run all discovered tests, select the play button at the top of Test Explorer:

[image]

To run a specific group of tests, or a single test, select the file, class, or test, then select the play button to the right of that item:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but no, it won't do, it's one of the first things I tried, but I get the same behavior, it only executes tests in **test_integration_comun.py** file :(

Comment: You can submit bugs in GitHub by yourself. After all, this involves some of your code. I can't submit it for you because I can't reproduce the problem